# Facebook Graph API getting friend photos

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wanted to know if someone knows why does the Graph API won't return some friends albums even though I can see them on their web profile. Also if the Graph API is limited to friends only, because I'm able to see some other people (non friends) albums but can't seem to get anything with the API calls.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe those friends don’t share their photos with apps that friends are using. And not everything that is available to you as a user on facebook.com is also available via API, that’s just how it is.

Comment: Never thought of that and you're actually right, I just checked my own privacy settings and found out that. Thanks a lot!